# how to check condtiotion for version check in bootstraper (wix)?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installation, wix3.6

I am using bootstraper to install VC++ and .net framework,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
 <Bundle Name="Engage" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="my Corporation" UpgradeCode="d7d559b1-3388-4275-91e2-d8d44d2f02db">
<BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense" />
<Chain>
  <!-- TODO: Define the list of chained packages. -->
  <PackageGroupRef Id="Netfx45FullPackage" />
  </Chain>
 </Bundle>
 <Fragment>
<PackageGroup Id="Netfx45FullPackage">
  <ExePackage Id="Netfx45Xxx" Cache="no" Compressed="no" PerMachine="yes" Permanent="yes" Vital="no" InstallCommand="/q" SourceFile=".\NDP452-x86-x64ENU.exe"  />
  <ExePackage Id="VC2013" Cache="no" Compressed="no" PerMachine="yes" Permanent="yes" Vital="no" InstallCommand="/q" SourceFile=".\vcredist_x862013.exe"  />

  <MsiPackage Id="MyProg" Cache="no" Compressed="no" DisplayInternalUI="yes" Vital="yes" SourceFile="D:\Projects\Crimson\engage.client\EngageSetupCreator\bin\Debug\EngageSetupCreator.msi" />
  </PackageGroup>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

currently iam installing those two without checking any condition, what should I do to check if the same version for vc++ and .netframework exist, and if exist skip the installation ?

no need to install again if already exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add detect condition and use registry search to get the installed version.

For example:

```
<?define NetFx451MinRelease = 378675 ?>

<util:RegistrySearchRef Id="NETFRAMEWORK45"/>

<ExePackage Id="NetFx451"
                ...
              DetectCondition="NETFRAMEWORK45 &gt;= $(var.NetFx451MinRelease)"
                ...
              >
</ExePackage>
```

Same for the vc++.

Comment: could you just explain what exactly &gt;= $(var.NetFx451MinRelease)"
 indicates?

Comment: 378675  what this indicates?

Comment: This is the version number. If your condition is. Net version 4.5.1 or higher, this way is how you do it.

Comment: mine is 4.5.2, from where I can get this number?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed

Comment: how this will change for visual c++? I couldnot find the logic, please help

Comment: Please mark as answered and open a new question for the c++ in detail.